# How to retry all celery tasks that fail due to database errors?

Tags: django, database, celery

We have multiple shared tasks in our django codebase that fetch data from db and manipulate. Is it possible to include a celery configuration that retries "all" failed tasks rather than adding "try-catch" in each individual task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `autoretry_for` option, see [celery docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-retry-for-known-exceptions)

UPD.
It could be more convenient not to provide the option for every task once you have specified it. Unfortunatelly at the time `autoretry_for` could only be passed as the task decorator argument, but there is a functional approach to do the trick

```
from functools import partial
from celery import shared_task

shared_task = partial(shared_task, autoretry_for=(RuntimeError,))))
```

Comment: autoretry_for can be done only on "task by task" basis. Can it be specified in celery configuration so that it can be done for all tasks? The error we are encountering is "Operational Error" where database fails to connect. There are multiple tasks throughout the project that use database related requests so it only makes sense for us to specify it in the configuration for all tasks to use.

Comment: to do that you may just add `autoretry_for` to celery config, along with broker_url, result_backend and others

Comment: Does this configuration specification work for shared_tasks as well? I might be asking something really stupid though.

Comment: Double checked, for some reason it is not applying from the config, so for now we are ended up with per task `autoretry_for`

Comment: Have you used task_annotations (https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#task-settings) ? Do you reckon "task_annotations = {'*': {'autoretry_for': '<Exception>'}}" might work? We havent used it so far in our project

Comment: Already tried it, unfortunately `autoretry_for` could only be pass as `task` decorator named argument, as the docs describes

Comment: Ah.. Thanks Greenv.